# Looping through xml with jquery and rendering results

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have some xml I'm trying to loop through in this format:

```
<nav>
  <folder>
    <form/>
    <form/>
  </folder>
  <folder>
    <form/>
    <form/>
  </folder>
</nav>
```

My jquery is supposed to loop through the xml and generate a mobile-style menu using lists:

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
$xml = $(xmlDoc);
$('#studentMobile').append("<ul>");
$xml.find('folder').each(function(i){   

$('#studentMobile ul').append($('<li>').append($("<a>").attr('href', '#').html($(this).attr("name")))); 
    if($(this).children().length != 0){
        console.log('Length: ' + $(this).children().length);
        $('#studentMobile ul').children().eq(i).addClass('has-sub'); 
        $('#studentMobile ul li').append('<ul>');

        $(this).children().each(function(j){
        $('#studentMobile ul li ul')
            .append($('<li>').attr('ondragstart', 'drag(event)').attr('draggable','true')
                .append($("<a>").attr('href', $(this).attr('url')).html($(this).attr("name"))));            
            });     
         }  
    });
```

It should generate a list that looks something like this:

```
<li class='has-sub' id="studentMobile"><a href='#'>Students</a>
     <ul>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Registration</a>
            <ul>
               <li ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"><a href='http://www.weather.com'>Register for Classes</a></li>
               <li ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"><a href='http://www.amazon.com'>Retake a Course (Academic Forgiveness)</a></li>
               <li ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"><a href='http://www.google.com'>View Your Holds</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
```

I'm not exactly sure if I'm using the nested .each correctly, because in my first loop, it generates ALL the form elements in the xml. It's also not rendering my html markup correctly, as it's nesting another 'ul' in my lowest 'li' child. Am I using the .each method correctly? I've also tried using $(this).find('form').each in my second loop, with the same results. I can include a sample of the html it's rendering if needed.

Comment: can you create a quick jsfiddle?